# Переопределение filter атрибута на уровне экшена

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Всем привет, пробую сделать атрибут, который будет ограничывать доступ к экшинам контроллеров.

При логине в claims добавляю значение, по котором буду смотреть, можно ли доступиться или нет.

Использую IFilterFactory для фильтрации, код фильтра:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AccessFilterAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    private AccessFilterMode _mode;

    public AccessFilterAttribute()
    {
        _mode = AccessFilterMode.None;
    }

    public AccessFilterAttribute(AccessFilterMode mode)
    {
        _mode = mode;
    }

    public bool IsReusable => false;

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new AccessFilterInternal(_mode);
    }

    private class AccessFilterInternal : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        private readonly AccessFilterMode _mode;

        public AccessFilterInternal(AccessFilterMode mode)
        {
            _mode = mode;
        }

        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {

            //тут проверки, если доступа нету - ошибка и другой фильтр обрабатывает это, если ошибок нету, то к другому обработчику в цепочке.

            if ()
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Errors = new[] { new { ErrorMessage = "You do not have permission to perform this action", ErrorCode = ErrorCode.NoPermissions } } });
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

затем добавляю новый атрибут к классу (для того чтобы не дублировать на каждый экшин и отдельно на метод с другим параметром:

```
[AccessFilter(AccessFilterMode.NotAll)]
public class SomeController
{
    [AccessFilter(AccessFilterMode.All)]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

И получается, что при запросе GetAsync() сначала срабатывает фильтр контроллера с параметром AccessFilterMode.NotAll а затем фильтр метода с параметром AccessFilterMode.All.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы фильтр на контроллере не срабатывал?

P.S. просто убрать его с контроллера и повесить на все методы не вариант, идея в том чтобы не дублировать везде.

Comment: Может посмотреть реализацию штатных `[Authorize]` и `[AllowAnonymous]`? Я бывало в базовом контроллере вешал [Authorize] и изредка переопределял на уровне экшена [AllowAnonymous], возможно глядя на их код что-то натолкнёт на идеи.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, смотрел, не помогло. Моя основная проблема в том, что на уровне контроллера выпадает ошибка (так и задумано) и экшин уже не срабатывает, т. е. надо отменить проверку на контроллере